Как не высчитывать сколько это значение в пикселях будет во вьюпортах для определённого экрана, а записать формулу с чем-то вроде calc()
Вот у меня есть отступ, например, row-gap: 20px для ширины экрана в 1200px; чтобы перевести это во вьюпорты, чтобы этот отступ был отзывчивым, мне нужно 20 поделить на 1200 и умножить это на 100. А как мне не высчитывать это, а записать формулу, с чем-то вроде calc()? Такой вариант row-gap: calc(20 / 1200 * 100)vw не работает.

row-gap: clamp(10px, calc(20 / 1200 * 100vw), 20px);

Это означает, что максимальное значение row-gap будет 20px, а при значениях меньше 1200px будет зависеть от вьюпорта, пока не уменьшится до 10px (минимальное значение).
